# Running SqlTransform Python SDK on local Apache Beam instalation. Error received: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'docker'"

Tags: python, docker, sdk, apache-beam

I am trying to test SqlTransform for Python SDK using a local Beam installation. To mention that Beam is installed in a virtual environment and I use Python 3.8.3. I am getting error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'docker'".

```
with beam.Pipeline() as p:
pc = (p | beam.Create([
    FruitRecipe("pie", "strawberry", 3, 1.5),
    FruitRecipe("muffin", "blueberry", 2, 2.),
    ])
    | beam.Map(lambda x: beam.Row(recipe = str(x[0]),  # str
                             fruit = str(x[1]),    # str
                             quantity = int(x[2]), # int
                             unit_cost = float(x[3]), # float
                             is_berry = bool(x[1].endswith('berry'))))) # bool
pc | SqlTransform(" SELECT * FROM PCOLLECTION WHERE quantity > 1")
```

The log:

> ---

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call

> last)  in 
> 9                                  unit_cost = float(x[3]), # float
> 10                                  is_berry = bool(x[1].endswith('berry'))))) # bool
> ---> 11     pc | SqlTransform(" SELECT * FROM PCOLLECTION WHERE quantity > 1")
>
> ~/PROJECTS/Apache_Beam/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py
> in **exit**(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
> 580     try:
> 581       if not exc_type:
> --> 582         self.result = self.run()
> 583         self.result.wait_until_finish()
> 584     finally:
>
> ........
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'docker'

Comment: Have you installed Docker? The SqlTransform is a special transform that is executed in a separate container.

Comment: No. I followed the installation instructions: https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/#set-up-your-environment.

Comment: Once installed docker, new error:  Kernel started: a0b26486-25c8-403a-9ed1-b97960c4cedf
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=apache%2Fbeam_java8_sdk&tag=2.27.0: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.

Comment: Although I tested docker was successfully installed by running the hello-world image.

Comment: In that case, you can also add Docker be able to be run without sudo. Fair warning, this gives Docker root privileges. https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Answer (score 1):

The SqlTransform in Apache Beam runs in a separate container. In order to run this transform (and other [cross-language transforms](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#create-x-lang-transforms)) you need to have docker [installed](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/) with [root privileges](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/), or at least run the pipeline with elevated privileges.

Comment: Thank you, it worked like this: I've added user to the docker group.

Comment: I have installed the docker and added my user to the docker group. When I run the script I get several times:  WARNING:root:Waiting for grpc channel to be ready at localhost:51221. and at the end:  raise ValueError("Unsupported signal: {}".format(sig))
ValueError: Unsupported signal: 2. What does that mean?